# readr - loading a zipped csv file

Tags: r, csv, readr

From this code:

```
require(readr)
readK6 <- read_csv("./data/K6.csv.zip", 
                   col_types = c("character", "numeric"))
```

I'm getting:

> Error: Unknown shortcut: h 
>   In addition: Warning message: Missing
>   column names filled in: 'X1' [1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sun0246apiwovyj/K6.csv.zip?dl=0)

When trying to load [this dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sun0246apiwovyj/K6.csv.zip?dl=0).

Any ideas?

---

edit: 
I want the first col to read as char and

```
readK6 <- read_csv("./data/K6.csv.zip", 
                    col_types=cols(
                      s = col_character(), 
                      x = col_double()
                      )
                    )
```

ain't working either.

Answer (score 3):

As your first column is missing a name it gets filled in automatically with `X1` (http://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html) as you can also see from the warning message you get. To force that column to read as `chr` you can use the following

```
library(readr)
readK6 <- read_csv("K6.csv.zip",
               col_types = cols(X1 = col_character(),
                                x = col_double()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
require(readr)
setwd("your work directory")
readK6 <- read_csv("K6.csv.zip")
```

You will receive the mensage `Missing column names filled in: 'X1'` because in the csv file the head of column one is missing.

```
> class(readK6)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> length(readK6)
[1] 2
> nrow(readK6)
[1] 2196277
> ncol(readK6)
[1] 2
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to read the first column as character too. ```readK6 <- read_csv("./data/K6.csv.zip", 
                   col_types=cols(
                     s = col_character(), 
                     x = col_double()
                     )
                   )
``` ain't working.